# How to add more user identity session attributes in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In Yii2 you can access the identity interface for the current user by using the identityInterface object from within the \yii\web\User class with something like this

```
 \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
```

**Is there a way to get and set additional parameters (without extending the identity class)?**

Basically a equivalent of Yii 1.x `getState()`, and `setState()` methods in `CWebUser` to store and retrieve session information like this

```
Yii::app()->user->setState("some_attribute",$value);
Yii::app()->user->getState('some_attribute',$defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay it seems this was removed intentionally to avoid "confusion". See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/167. So the only way to do this  by calling the session class directly.

```
\Yii::$app->session->set('user.attribute',$value);
\Yii::$app->session->get('user.some_attribute');
```

Because it now stored directly in session without prefix it is best to namespace the keys with identifiers  like `user.xxxx` to avoid collision with some other key set at different point of the application.

Answer (score 12):

The best way to add attributes to user is creating public attribute in your User Class.

```
class Yiidentity extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface{
       public $awesomeAttribute = "foo";
}
```

How to use:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->awesomeAttribute;
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer. No need to call the session class here.
Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Where would you put this class in the context of basic and advanced app? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In Yii2 **\Yii::$app->user->identity** contain instance of the identityClass. So, if you want some identityClass-related data - just use it like instance of the identityClass.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this would be done? How would I create a new attribute to use elsewhere in the application?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a **getter** function to include additional identity information for the user. For example, retrieve `fullname` from a profile table.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    // Other code goes here...       
    public function getFullname()
    {
        $profile = Profile::find()->where(['user_id'=>$this->id])->one();
        if ($profile !==null)
            return $profile->fullname;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it as if you have an attribute named `fullname`, like so

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->fullname;
```