# Store $_POST in Yii2 session

Tags: session-variables, yii2

I'm having a little trouble with my quiz form. I'm using a page to show a single question that a user answers, from there I was hoping to save the question id and option id (My form is multiple choice, i set the options).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="question[3]" value="4">My Answer
```

When the form is posted I am doing this

```
if(isset(Yii::$app->session['question'])){

                // Get posted array
                $question = $_POST['question'];
                Yii::$app->session['question'] = $question;
                print_r(Yii::$app->session['question']);
            }
```

So it's saved into my session as:

```
Array
(
[3] => 4
)
```

Which is fine, the problem I'm finding is trying to save the next question without overwriting the previous [question_id] => [option_id].

I understand why the following code just overwrites the existing the session['question'] variable. But I'm struggling to be able to save each question and answer array to my variable.

I have tried `Yii::$app->session['question'][$i] = $question;` and get `Indirect modification of overloaded element of yii\web\Session has no effect`

I've also tried `array_push` and `array_merge` to try and combine the previous array of question and chosen option, but have had no luck either. What am I doing wrong here please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079781/how-to-add-more-user-identity-session-attributes-in-yii2

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is

```
$q = $_POST['question'];
Yii::$app->session['question'] = array_merge(Yii::$app->session['question'], [$question]);
```

Comment: Yii:$app->session should be Yii::$app->session - notice double ::

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
Yii::$app->session['question'][] = $question;
```

Notice the extra []