# yii2 How to transfer post data from one view to two?

Tags: yii2

I am trying to create make a two-step form in yii2.

This is my SiteController.php

```
public function actionCreateCharacter()
{
    $model = new Character();
    var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Character'));
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $attributes=['imie','nazwisko','plec','wyznanie_id'];
        if ($step1 = $model->validate($attributes)) {
            //var_dump($step1);
            // form inputs are valid, do something here
            //var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Character');

            return $this->render('createCharacterStep2', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);;
        }
        else {
            // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
            $errors = $model->errors;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('createCharacter', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreateCharacterStep2()
{
    $model2 = new Character();
    var_dump($model);
    if ($model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Character'));
        if ($model2->validate()) {
            // form inputs are valid, do something here
            return;
        }
    }

    /*return $this->render('createCharacter2', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);*/
}
```

... and this is my Character.php (model + attributeLabels and tableName)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'imie', 'nazwisko', 'plec', 'wyznanie_id', 'avatar_src', 'avatar_svg'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'wyznanie_id'], 'integer'],
        [['avatar_svg'], 'string'],
        [['imie'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
        [['nazwisko'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['plec'], 'string', 'max' => 1],
        [['avatar_src'], 'string', 'max' => 30]
    ];
}
```

I have access to `$_POST` by `Yii::$app->request->post()` in `createCharacter` - I get `imie`, `nazwisko`, `plec` and `wyznanie_id`.

But when I send the form in step 2 I have only post data from step 2.

How can I set the post data from step1+step2?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: Save data to session

Comment: How to do it?
Normaly $_SESSION['key']=value?

Comment: i think i found: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169991/store-post-in-yii2-session)

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: ok, and how to save session to post that i could use $model->validate()

Comment: `$session['step1_data'] = Yii::$app->request->post()` and in 2nd step `$model->load(array_merge($session['step1_data'], Yii::$app->request->post()))` for example. But you will need validation scenarios for required fields etc also. And preload to the 1st form data from session

Comment: tkanks you very much :)

Comment: You might want to take a look to https://github.com/beastbytes/yii2-wizard. It implements exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, i know what is yii2-wizard, but i cant implement this ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rendering step2 from step1 action, you can always pass additional data to controller's action. So I added "STEPONEPOSTS" post variable which contains all posts of step 1. Check below.

```
public function actionCreateCharacter()
{
    $model = new Character();
    var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Character'));
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $attributes=['imie','nazwisko','plec','wyznanie_id'];
        if ($step1 = $model->validate($attributes)) {
            //var_dump($step1);
            // form inputs are valid, do something here
            //var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Character');

            return $this->render('createCharacterStep2', [
                'model' => $model,
                'STEPONEPOSTS' => Yii::$app->request->post(),
            ]);;
        }
        else {
            // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
            $errors = $model->errors;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('createCharacter', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

And now in step 2 view, you can get step 1 posts variable as

```
$STEPONEPOSTS
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way , if you have to table for `step 1` and `step 2`. then save the data of step 1 first then step2 data. 
 if you are not using two tables then you can create two form each form for each step and also create `scenarios` for each step according to the fields.
I think this may help . `You can use session also as per discussion in comments or you can use the extension array wizard` 
but array wizard extension is not well documented , so i suggest you try my way i will help you.

Comment: Exactly, i have one table in DB and i wanted to create 2 form (step) for one model.